# Android Studio adds libapp.so to the resulting apk, what is it and how to turn it off?

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk

Android Studio 1.1 generated apk file (located @ app/build/outputs/apk folder) contains the lib directory, and for every cpu type there exists a non-empty folder, like /x86. Each of these folder contain a libapp.so shared library that is around 5Kb in size per cpu.

I've searched the net and the only thing I found so far is this link from Intel https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/building-native-android-apps-using-intelr-c-compiler-in-android-studio that shows how to change the default libapp.so to user-provided library.

So, I guess that this library (libapp.so) is somehow built by gradle.

In fact I do my own native library building, using ndk-build command line tool, and my libs are placed alongside that libapp.so. It's not causing any issues btw, but I feel that I'm losing the control over what is built and why.

Here's my humble build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

 /**
 * Path to *.so files
 */
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/libs']
            jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build
        }
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.android"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

How can I disable this libapp.so being built?

Answer (score 0):

defaultConfig {
  ndk {
      moduleName "yourSelfLib"
  }
}